# Updated data not retrieving with Hibernate session and MDB in a transaction

Tags: hibernate, jms

I have a method which is doing multiple operation in a transaction. On of the operation is sending message to MDB. I am using hibernate with spring framework.

Pseudo code is :

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public someMethod{  

dao.update(someObject);  

sendToMDB(someObjectID);    << sending ID of above updated object

dao.doSomeThingMore();
}
```

In the MDB i am just fetching the above updatedObject :

```
onMessage(){
```

`....`

```
dao.find(someObjectID);

}
```

The problem I am facing is when i retrieve someObject in MDB its retrieving the old values of someObject and not the updated ones!!!

I tried to take away all methods in MDB and put all together in method someMethod() and it works all fine. 
I even tried using flush() & clear()  after dao.update() but still same problem.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can someone please suggest. This problem is making me wild.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to create transactional  queue session.

```
QueueSession createQueueSession(
        QueueConnection qu
    ) throws JMSException {
    return qu.createQueueSession(true, -1);
}
```

Note here **true** parameter will make  session transactional. Here -1  just dummy parameter when you want to neglect acknowledgement param , you may use predefined ack modes though.

Also there may be some transactional configurations you can set in your applications server console  if needed to make calls transactional.